# Performance issue when transferring data from Oracle to SQL Server using a SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis

I am doing an ETL in a SSIS package using an Oracle source and SQL Server destination.

The source contains about 17 million rows. When transferring the data, it is done in batches of 10000 rows. Each 10000 rows will be committed to the SQL Server destination when done.

When we observe the time taken for the transfer we can notice that the first 10000 rows took 2 seconds and it gradually increased throughout the load and last 10000 rows took 132 seconds. The duration vs rowset number graph is as follows. What could be the reason for the load time to increase exponentially?

[image]

We are using a script in the SSIS package to pull the data from the Oracle source.

There are 2 indexes on the destination SQL server table. one on the primary key(clustered) and the next on a date column(non-unique, non-clustered). But we are first loading to a temp table on SQL server which doesn't have any indexes. After the transfer is completed to the temp table then we are transferring the data to the actual table with indexes.

Comment: Have you done any tracing to see where the time is being spent-- on the source database, in the destination database, or in the SSIS server?  The graph looks consistent with an inefficient paging query to get sets of 10,000 rows but knowing nothing about what you're doing, that's a wild guess.

Comment: It is a simple read from Oracle and Bulk Insert to SQL Server. We expected the graph to be flat i.e. same time for each 10,000 blocks.

Comment: Yes, but are you  pushing or pulling?

Comment: Is this a dataflow or are you landing the data to a file and then bulk inserting it?  I would be good if you could share how things are configured.  Also, does the destination table have indexes and constraints?  How are you pulling the data from oracle?

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz updated the question answering some of your questions.

Comment: @MitchWheat we are using the SSIS package to pull data from the Oracle source

Comment: @SubashBasnayake, could you try running the job without the bulkcopy?  I would like to know if the reads are getting slower or if it is definitely the writes.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the oracle oledb driver. We were using the 19.0 driver previously which gave us this performance issue. After changing to the 12.1 driver the data load looks like below. Throughout the load, the 10000 row sets took around 3-5 seconds.
[image]